# Which SObjects support LWC Quick Actions?

Tags: lightning-web-components, quickaction, lightning-quickaction

The [Documentation for LWC Quick Actions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_quick_actions) doesn't make any mention of supported SObjects, or restrictions on the use of LWC Quick Actions for certain object types.  However, when I tried to create one for the `Asset` standard object, I received an error:

> Error: Lightning Web Component quick actions are not supported for this entity

[image]

Interestingly, the label "Lightning Web Component" changed to "Visualforce Page" and the component name changed to an Id, but that's not really relevant to the issue.

In this instance, I had already built the LWC but couldn't configure it; I ended up having to go a different route.  I understand that not all "standard" objects are very standard at all, and that support for new features increases over time.  Mostly I'd like to avoid wasted effort.  Is there a definitive list of SObject types for which LWC Quick Actions are supported?

Comment: I could have sworn this was in the documentation somewhere, but I also can't find it now. I do know that the list of supported objects is still really small. It'll probably be expanded in the Winter 22 release. Try it out in a Prerelease sandbox when you get access to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Create a Lightning Web Component Action](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lightning_web_component_actions_create.htm&type=5) has this documented:

> You can create a Lightning web component action for **custom objects** and
> for **some standard objects**.
>
> - Account
> - Contact
> - Lead
> - Opportunity
> - Case

With the following being noted specifically for `Case`

> IMPORTANT You can add a Lightning web component action to the
> Highlights Panel of a case record page if you add it as a dynamic
> action in Lightning App Builder. You can't use the page layout to add
> a Lightning web component action to the Highlights Panel of a case
> record.

Comment: Great find, thanks.  I commented on the help page that such info should be in the Developer docs; hopefully that will happen at some point.